# Why do you have to start over if the oleh makes the bracha at the wrong place?

Tags: blessing, torah-reading, mistakes, ki-teitzei

Towards the end of Shoftim, there's a parsha that begins כי תצא למלחמה על אויביך, but it's not the correct beginning of Ki Teitzei.  If the oleh makes the bracha having in mind the wrong כי תצא, he has to make the bracha again (Tikkun Simanim and I've seen this happen, though not this week).

Why can't you just start reading from there and have a slightly longer rishon?  Then it won't have been a bracha levatala.

A similar precedent: there are sometimes minyanim for Mincha on Shabbos the last day of Pesach or Shavuos that read the entire parsha to let people traveling to Israel catch up.

Comment: Can you link the halacha mentioned in the 1st paragraph? (I think O.C. may state the same thing, but I have to look that up.) I'm guessing that the reason for not allowing the 1st idea is that the bracha that is made assumes knowing the correct place to start. Originally, that was no "Ba'al Kriah", as is more common, now. Each person lained his own portion. That may have been the origin that the oleh needs to know exactly where to begin. Probably, the same responsibility, now, though, it seems that most olim can't find the place. Interesting research for me...  I've frequently made that error.

Comment: @DanF I'm not sure how the ba'al korei is relevant.  Either way, Ki Teitzei is the beginning of the parsha, so somebody is finding it from scratch.  The ba'al korei and the oleh have the same opportunity to make a mistake.

Comment: Several times I have leined Rishon of Ki Seitzei, and almost every time have I made this mistake. Every time I’ve been told just to start from Ki Seitzei without the Oleh making a new bracha.

Comment: @DonielF which ki seitzei were you told to start from?

Comment: The correct one

Comment: @DonielF & Heshy, I've no source at hand but IINM you bless again unless the correct spot was visible to the _ole_ before he first blessed.

Comment: @msh210 by visible do you mean the Sefer Torah just has to be open wide enough?   It's plausible that it would be for this case.  Or does the oleh actually have to know where it is?

Comment: I meant the first one.

Comment: @msh210 I don’t recall in my case if that column was visible or not.